# Laravel HTTP Client post request not working

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Try to get Access Token From Instagram

```
       $params = array(
            'app_id' => $this->clientId,
            'app_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
            'code' => $this->request->code
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        $endpoint = $this->getBaseUrl() . 'oauth/access_token';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);


        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
        $body = substr($response, $header_size);
        dd($response,$header_size,$header,$body);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        return $response;
```

this code with CURL working fine.

[Request Data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data) Laravel Documentation.

```
$response = Http::post($this->getBaseUrl() . 'oauth/access_token', [
            'app_id' => $this->clientId,
            'app_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
            'code' => $this->request->code
        ]
    );
   return $response->body();
```

but not working with Laravel Http Client.it **return Client Id is missing** but I'm sending as parameter.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. It seems almost that you are trying to access your own OAuth every point, correct? Anyway, shouldn't you be sending `client_id` instead of `app_id`, as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#requesting-tokens

Comment: what is the content-type of the request

Comment: @MaartenVeerman to get Access Token From Instagram.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, try to use `asForm()`,

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post($this->getBaseUrl() . 'oauth/access_token', [
            'app_id' => $this->clientId,
            'app_secret' => $this->clientSecret,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => $this->redirectUrl,
            'code' => $this->request->code
        ]
    );
return $response->json();
```

Comment: Yep this did it for me, Cheers