# How to send POST request to other localhost via http client request in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

I want my laravel application to send a post request to another laravel application

my first application is running on the 127.0.0.1:8000 server and the other is on the 127.0.0.1:8001 server

only GET request works

here is my code for making HTTP client post request in the 127.0.0.1:8001 server

```
public function registration(Request $request)
{
    
    $response = Http::post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/pre-register', [
        'lname'=>$request->lname,
        'fname'=>$request->fname,
        'username'=>$request->username,
        'password'=>$request->password,
    ]);
    return $response->json();
}
```

and I want to send it to the 127.0.0.1:8000 server

and in my 127.0.0.1:8000 server

```
public function preRegistration(Request $request)
{

    Registration::create([
        'fname'=>$request->fname, 
        'lname'=>$request->lname, 
        'uname'=>$request->username, 
        'password'=>Hash::make($request->password), 
        //'avatar'=>$hasMoved
    ]);


    return back();
}
```

it returns a blank page

how to make a post request?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel HTTP Client post request not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219832/laravel-http-client-post-request-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you able to see json string after posting on your first app?
2. Is it possinle "lname:fname" to "fname:lname" order is causing issues?
3. Can you do your register like;

   $registered_user = Registration::create([
   'fname'=>$request->fname,
   'lname'=>$request->lname,
   'uname'=>$request->username,
   'password'=>Hash::make($request->password),
   //'avatar'=>$hasMoved
   ]);

and then return $registered_user to your first server as json response again?